# Modified font licensing

Tags: font-licensing

So I've downloaded a free for personal use font. I've used it for a logo, but changed some of the lettering as it didn't fit my design (created outlines).

Do I need to buy the commercial license?

Comment: What license is it exactly?

Comment: To use it commercially... Ive designed for a restaurant. EULA? Im just worried about covering my arse if you know what I mean?

Comment: Sounds commercial to me. Given that you yourself depend on similar things for income, it would be bad form for you to not heed the license. Do unto others an so on...

Comment: True. I know thats the right thing, its just when you speak to some, they say No need...

Comment: If you want a legal answer you should ask on [law.se]. If you want a non-legal answer: buy the license. How would you feel if someone took your work without paying?

Comment: Was just a question....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you used it commercially. That you modified it isn't relevant legally.

Answer (score 1):

If the logo is for a commercial enterprise (any kind of store, restaurant, business, etc), then your use IS considered commercial. Modification of the font does not mean that you did not use the font. Therefore you need to pay the commercial use licence.